# Should "Ubuntu Software" center allow (with a checkbox) also to see the installed apps grouped by their categories?

Tags: software-center

For easier view and when searching for an app and for overall understanding of one's apps.

And allow choosing sorting by name or size or installed date.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This site works a bit differently than other sites you may be used to. Take the [tour](https://askubuntu.com/tour) or visit the [help center](https://askubuntu.com/help) for more information. Specifically, we don't do opinion-based questions here, which this one seems to be. You might want to check out the Ubuntu [Discourse](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/) for that, it seems like a topic you could discuss there. Or you can open a feature request issue on Ubuntu's Gnome Software Gitlab page, or the upstream GNOME gitlab page.